# Emacs: Keyboard Macros and Dired

Tags: emacs, dired

Is there an emacs command which would apply a kbd macro to every file in dired?

e.g. `query-replace-regexp` has `dired-do-query-replace-regexp`

I'm looking for a `dired-do-call-last-kbd-macro`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to do this:

1. go to the top of your dired buffer
2. Record Macro
3. Press enter to visit the file
4. M-x kmacro-call-ring-2nd
5. C-x o (other buffer)
6. Down a line
7. Stop Recording
8. C-u 0 C-x e (call-last-keyboard-macro till the end of the file)

Comment: Interesting, but you shold not that you need to load kmacro first (a library I had never seen before).

Answer (score 1):

C-h f dired-do-query-replace-regexp reveals the code for this:

```
(dolist (file (dired-get-marked-files nil nil 'dired-nondirectory-p))
    (let ((buffer (get-file-buffer file)))
      (if (and buffer (with-current-buffer buffer
            buffer-read-only))
      (error "File `%s' is visited read-only" file))))
```

I'd just make some elisp that does what you want using this as a template

Comment: That is only the part that displays an error message. The part that does the replacing is this:

(tags-query-replace from to delimited
        '(dired-get-marked-files nil nil 'dired-nondirectory-p))

But the code you posted is probably better to base the code on anyway.